Reactjs, StricMode calling setState twice. Alternative and best practices
Technical question here. I created a context provider to handle the state of some variables and to create functions to update these variables from other components. It is of my understanding that StricMode calls setStates twice, however, how are we supposed to handle pushing/popping elements from data arrays within states without duplicating these actions.
This is my context.jsx:


export const BrollProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //These are the states in question
  const [bRollItems, setbRollItems] = useState([]);
  const [timelineData, setTimelineData] = useState([
    {
        id: "0",
        actions: []
    },
  ]);
  
  //This is the function that upon being called updates the states
  const addBrollItemAndAction = (event, currentFrame) => {
    //Some irrelevant variables
    event.preventDefault();
    const bRollItemId = event.dataTransfer.getData('bRollItemId');
    const newAction = {
        id: bRollItemId,
        start: currentFrame / 30,
        end: (currentFrame / 30) + 3,
        isSelected: true,
        effectId: ''
      };
      
    //Next we have the setStates, regardless of the logic within them, they always get called twice
      
    //First setState, doesn't matter if it's called twice since it works on the same object everytime (id === id)
    setbRollItems((prevItems) =>
        prevItems.map((item) =>
            item.id === bRollItemId ? 
                { ...item, 
                    addedToTimeline: true, 
                    startFrame: currentFrame, durationInFrames: 90,
                    width:'85%',
                    transform: 'translate(32px, 37px)'
                } : item
        )
    );

    //This setState adds data to the existing timelineData array, so everytime we call it, 2 identical objects are .pushed to the data array.
    setTimelineData((prevTimelineData) => {
      const updatedData = [...prevTimelineData];
      const lastRow = updatedData[updatedData.length - 1];

      if (lastRow && lastRow.actions.length === 0) {
        lastRow.actions.push(newAction);
      } else {
        const newRow = {
          id: (parseInt(lastRow.id) + 1).toString(),
          actions: [newAction]
        };
        updatedData.push(newRow);
      }
      return updatedData;
    });

  };
  

  return (
    <BrollContext.Provider value={{ bRollItems, setbRollItems, timelineData, setTimelineData, addBrollItemAndAction }}>
      {children}
    </BrollContext.Provider>
  );
};



Now the addBrollItemAndAction function is called from another component (simplified for clarity):


const MyComponent = ({ propss }) => {
  const { bRollItems, setbRollItems, timelineData, setTimelineData, addBrollItemAndAction } = useMyCustomContextHook(); 
  const currentFrame = someIntValue
  
  const handleBrollDrop = (event) => {
        addBrollItemAndAction(event, currentFrame)
    }
    
  return(
    <div onDrag={handleBrollDrop}>
      <MyOtherComponent/>
    </div>
  )
}



When I disable StrictMode the issue is pretty much fixed, but not the underlying cause. With that being said, what is the best practice to modify arrays of data in developer mode? Specifically with .push() if you don't want the same variable being pushed twice to the same state. And how come updating an array with .push() may cause bugs in the future? Seems pretty straightforward to me. Are we supposed to do workarounds or is this a measure taken by strictMode so we don't use useState for what I'm intending to use it for?

I would normally expect a useEffect to cause a double action like this with react strict mode.
but besides that push is a mutation, so that can mess up things in react. try using the spread opperator, like [...oldArray, newArrayElement]. One last thing, maybe it might be easier to breakdown your code by popping out these set state functions and passing values to them as pure functions, then they can be unit tested so you can garantee that they work as intended in isolation, just a suggestion, I know it can be hard to find the time to do this kinda work

Unfortunately using the spread operator didn't fix the issue, I used updatedData = [...updatedData, newRow]; but still, it was run twice, adding 2 objects to the data array.

What ended up fixing it was making a deep copy of the original state AND the spread operator, thanks!!!

good work! yeah, the deep copy is needed when you have objects or arrays inside other objects or arrays. since they are each left as a ref instead of a new version.

What ended up fixing the issue was creating a deep copy of the state object array so instead of:
const updatedData = [...prevTimelineData];

This still holds a reference to the original state which causes direct mutations which is a no-no in React
The right way to clone the state is:
const updatedData = prevTimelineData.map(row => ({ ...row }));

If I understand correctly, this creates a whole different copy of the state and doesnt affect it directly.
